# Looking to run a gate on a self hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have the requirement to set up a gate in my release to validate a few things. The validation must occur inside of my network, so using any of the out of the box gate options will not work.

Is it possible to have a gate run on a self-hosted agent and perform some PowerShell so I have complete access to my own network? I can change my jobs to run on a self-hosted agent, is it possible and how would I go about doing the same with a gate?

I could build a task in the stage to do the validation, however I need the retries that a gate provides as I assume that when the stage is hit that it will fail, but eventually pass.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have a gate run on a self-hosted agent and perform some PowerShell so I have complete access to my own network?

I am afraid we could not run a gate on a self-hosted agent at this moment.

Although we can run the jobs on a self-hosted agent, when we are in the deploy gate, whether it is the `Invoke REST API` or `Query Work Items`, the request is sent to the server and executed, and the execution result is returned. So we could not run the gate on a self-hosted agent.

To resolve this issue, you can try to create a Azure DevOps Server to deploy the gate:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/install/single-server?view=azure-devops

Hope this helps.